# Showing that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x}{n(1+nx^2)}$ Converges Uniformly via the Weierstrass M-test

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

**Setting:** Let $f_n(x):\mathbb{R} \rightarrow  \mathbb{R}$ s.t.

$$
f_n(x) = \frac{x}{n(1+nx^2)}
$$

and let $f$ denote the series of the $\{f_n\}$:

$$
f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x}{n(1+nx^2)}
$$

I am trying to show that $\{\sum_{n=1}^n f_n\}$ is uniformly convergent to $f$.  Assuming I'm not mistaken below, I've shown the desired result up to $|x| \ge 1$.  But I'm not sure how to proceed in case $|x| < 1$.

**Attempt in case $|x| \ge 1$:**

1. Let $x \in \mathbb{R}$ satisfy $|x| \ge 1$.
2. Then consider that

   $$
   \left| \frac{x}{n(1+nx^2)} \right| = \left| \frac{x}{n+n^2x^2} \right| \le \frac{|x|}{n^2x^2} = \underbrace{\frac{1}{|x| n^2} \le \frac{1}{n^2}}_{\text{ making use of $|x| \ge 1$}}
   $$
3. Since $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} < 2$ (a fact from calculus), we have that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x}{n(1+nx^2)}$ converges uniformly by the [Weierstrass M-test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_M-test) (with the $\{1/n^2\}$ serving as the $\{M_n\}$ using the notation from the link).

But this argument doesn't work in case $|x| < 1$ (as flagged in the inequality).  Is there a simple fix in my inequality reasoning that gets me to the desired result?

Comment: Just for your curiosity, $f(x)=x \left(\psi ^{(0)}\left(1+\frac{1}{x^2}\right)+\gamma \right)$ where appears the $digamma$ function and Euler constant.

Comment: A simple derivative analysis shows the maximum of $|f_n(x)|$ is $1/(2n^{3/2})$.

Comment: OP, you were right, my suggestion does not work, so I think that David Mitra's solution is probably the easiest.

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to split the problem into two cases. Instead, just notice that
$$
f_n(x) = \frac{x}{n(1+nx^2)}\implies f'_n(x)={1-nx^2\over n(1+nx^2)^2}=0 \text{ when } x=\pm{1\over \sqrt{n}},
$$
and these maximize $|f_n(x)|$. So take
$$
M_n=\left|f_n\left(\pm {1\over \sqrt{n}}\right)\right|={1\over 2n^{3/2}}>0.
$$
Then
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty M_n={1\over 2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty {1\over n^{3/2}}
$$
which converges since it is a $p$-series with $p=3/2>1$. By the Weierstrass $M$-Test, 
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n(x)
$$
converges uniformly.